# Complementarity in KKT conditions

Tags: karush-kuhn-tucker

What is the meaning of Complementarity in Karush–Kuhn–Tucker?

"In mathematical optimization, the Karush–Kuhn–Tucker (KKT) conditions, also known as the Kuhn–Tucker conditions, are first-order necessary conditions for a solution in nonlinear programming to be optimal, provided that some regularity conditions are satisfied."

Thank you!

Comment: Cf. [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1954110/66081)